# How to make a div AND its text not show on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I have a div (circle) and text that I want to show only on desktop.

```
<div class="circle">Text Here</div>
```

I can hide the circle fine using this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.circle{
//Circle design
}
}
```

However, the 'Text Here' within the Div still shows.

Anyone know how to hide the text too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below

```
CSS:
 .circle{
display:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
.circle{
display:block;
}
```

}

Option 2:
CSS

```
     .circle{
    visibility:hidden;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 600px){
    .circle{
    visibility:visible;
    }
}
```

Option3:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .circle{
    display:none;
    }
}
```

codepen URL for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JNXypz

Answer (score 0):

If the browser window is smaller than 600px, show the element with `class="circle"`

```css
.circle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .circle {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Text Here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `display:none;`in your media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .circle {
       display:none;
   }
}
```

Right now it's displayed as a block but now it'll be displayed as none when it hits 600px wide.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `max-width` instead?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio , min-width will make it unavailable for desktop

Comment: @NagaSaiA This approach uses `display: none` so `max-width` is the right one. `min-width` if you're using `display: block`.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio max-width: 600px looks fine and it works :)